# MySQL: Check if value within group

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a database with races in. I want to check to see if within a group a column contains a value.

So something like:

```
SELECT count(*) as total 
FROM table 
WHERE column contains value 'hurdal' 
   OR column contains value 'chase' 
GROUP BY column
```

Then I can see how many contain that value within the group.

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: SELECT count(*) as total FROM `table` WHERE `column` IN ('hurdal',  'chase') GROUP BY column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MySQL for checking contain you need [LIKE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like) operator, Like this:

```
SELECT count(*) as total 
FROM table 
WHERE column LIKE '%hurdal%' 
   OR column LIKE '%chase%' 
GROUP BY column
```

Answer (score 2):

`select count(*) as total from table where column in ('hurdal', 'chase') group by column`

`IN` checks the column value is contained within the group specified, thus this will match any row where `column` is either `hurdal` or `chase`.

For more information, the MySQL specific documentation is [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in), but this is a standard SQL operator so should work on any DBMS.

Comment: @JayBlanchard yep, I was in the process of rewording it already :)

Comment: You could also do this in an array to make it easier to add additional elements.

Comment: @TheSk8rJesus yes, if whatever MySQL client library lets you do that. I'm aware the question is tagged with mysqli and php, but the question neither mentions specific libraries or languages, and neither does my answer :)